# Boost scoped lock (mutex)

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to ask if syntax:

```
boost::scoped_lock(mutex);
```

is proper ? Compiling process running without any issues.

Comment: *Compiling process running without any issues.* You answered your own question. If this was incorrect syntax the compiler would have issued an error.

Comment: Maybe it was wrong question, is that syntax works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `scoped_lock` is a variable, which unlocks the mutex when the execution leaves it's scope. You should use it like:

```
boost::scoped_lock var_lock(mutex);
```

Example:

```
if(true){ // scope
  boost::scoped_lock var_lock(mutex);
  // mutex locked here
}
// var_lock destroyed, mutex unlocked
```